# Converting nested dictionary to json

Tags: python, json

```
search_data = {
                "attributes":
                {
                    "first_name": self.firstname,
                    "last_name": self.lastname,
                    "phone": self.phone,
                    "email": self.email
                }
            }
```

How to convert "search_data" dictionary to json such that i can pass it in python requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `requests.post(..., json=search_data)`.

It will JSON encode the data and set the content-type request header accordingly.